# name servers for Kubernetes DNS records

Tags: kubernetes, dns, nameservers

I want to use an external host service with my Kubernetes app. Where can I find the values for the name servers for Kubernetes?

Comment: What specific problem are you having?  `kube-dns` runs as a pod and doesn't have a specific set of IP addresses, but there are ways to tell it to serve other things.

Comment: cool thanks i didn't know that. The domain works now but I get this error have you seen it bevore my chance?

Comment: {
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {
    
  },
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "forbidden: User \"system:anonymous\" cannot get path \"/\": No policy matched.",
  "reason": "Forbidden",
  "details": {
    
  },
  "code": 403
}

Comment: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/ is worth reading.

Comment: if you still have an issue, please update the question or ask a new one.